# mockito does not verify that my method is invoked

Tags: java, mockito, junit4

I have the following two statements in my test class

```
    Mockito.verify(customvalueProcessorFactory, times(1)).get(customvalueKey, userId);
    when(customvalueProcessorFactory.get(customvalueKey, userId)).thenReturn(customvalueProcessor);
```

the second one works correctly and returns the passed value, which I use later in my tests. But the first one raises an error like the following:

```
-> at <my-path>.MessageProcessorUnitTest.expectCustomvalueProcessorFactoryGetCalledWillReturn(MessageProcessorUnitTest.java:194)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Verify after it happens

Comment: Where is the actual call to customvalueProcessorFactory.get(customvalueKey, userId) happening? Can you post the entire method please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general usage pattern in mockito is:

```
when(mock.doSomething()).then ...

doTheThingYouAreTesting();

verify(mock).doSomething();
```

You appear to have your verify first. Try changing your code to follow the pattern above.